# Wordpress - Text goes out from the widget

Tags: css, wordpress

Look at the photo attached.

1) Under the title , I removed author name with a plugin but "/" still appears before the date. - **How to remove "/"**

2) In the sidebar, when I create a poll, all answers goes out from the box!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mtdyc.png

**link:** shop.gabimolocea.com

Tell me if you need any files

Comment: We can't debug a photo.

Comment: you have the link inside : shop.gabimolocea.com

Comment: We're not a debugging service. Tell us what you've tried and what has not worked.

Comment: I do not find the path to remove "/" from meta.

Comment: @Molocea Gabriel you check my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is possible with code but for that need to check file but now can you add below css code in style.css to get result:

1) Under the title , I removed author name with a plugin but "/" still appears before the date. - Help me remove the "/"

**css code:**

```
.p-meta > span:first-child { display: none; }
```

2) In the sidebar, when I create a poll, all answers goes out from the box!

**css code:**

```
.yop-poll-forms ul li { width: 100% !important; }
```

add code and check it work for you.

Comment: css code:

li.yop-poll-li-answer-3_yp570dc5fe25472 { width: 100% !important; }
add code and check it work for you.

Comment: add in style.css also mark up vote for answer so other can get solution like above problem

Comment: doesn't work! I have added it in style.css ( renew.css in my case ) and doesn't work

Comment: i added it in the css of the theme. Maybe it should go in the css of the plugin, but the plugin has a lot of .css files

Comment: can you try .yop-poll-forms ul li { width: 100% !important; } in css

Comment: i can't press the up arrow,  i need 15 reputation to do this. But i checked right answer

Comment: Can you please male +1 vote now I think you have 15 reputation

Answer (score 0):

These are just quick fixes:

1. You'll need to edit the loop properly to achieve this - if you can post the loop code, I can show what you need to edit.
2. Remove width (width: 271px;) from that particular "li" element in CSS